# what does revert commit mean in gitkraken?

Tags: git, gitkraken

What does revert commit mean in git? Cause I pressed it when I right click on that specific highlighted commit. 
[image]

Comment: The definition of [revert](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/revert) in a dictionary is pretty spot on as to what it means. You get a new commit that removes the changes in that commit.

Answer (score 1):

The [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) page in the official git documentation expains in detail what `revert` does: `revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them`